# Why the first $x$ decimal places of $(5+\sqrt{26})^{x}$ are following a pattern?

Tags: exponentiation, irrational-numbers, decimal-expansion, pattern-recognition

$\sqrt{26}$ is irrational number, so the decimal places should show no pattern.
But $(5+\sqrt{26})^{x}$ has these values:

```
x=1                    10.0990195135...
x=2                  101.99019513592...
x=3                1030.000970872871...
x=4              10401.9999038646405...
x=5            105050.00000951927653...
x=6          1060901.999999057405867...
x=7        10714070.0000000933352124...
x=8      108201601.99999999075799265...
x=9    1092730090.000000000915139071...
x=10 11035502501.9999999999093833742...
...
```

Where does the pattern of decimal places comes from?

Comment: The digits to the left of the decimal point are [OEIS sequence A034807](https://oeis.org/A034807) "Triangle T(n,k) of coefficients of Lucas (or Cardan) polynomials".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a big hint.  Let $$f(x) = (5 + \sqrt{26})^x + (5 - \sqrt{26})^x.$$  Then $f(0) = 2$, $f(1) = 10$, and in general for $x = 2, 3, \ldots$, we have the recursion relation
$$f(x)f(1) = f(x+1) + (5 + \sqrt{26})(5 - \sqrt{26})f(x-1) = f(x+1) - f(x-1),$$ or $$f(x+1) = 10f(x) + f(x-1).$$  Consequently, $f(x)$ is an integer for every nonnegative integer $x$.

Now consider the magnitude of $5 - \sqrt{26}$; in particular, note it is less than $1$.  So successive integer powers of this number will tend toward $0$.

Comment: If I understand correctly, this only tells us that $a^n$ is close to an integer. It doesn't explain the apparent pattern, that the first $k$ digits consist only of zeros and nines, and that $k$ is roughly linear in the exponent.

Comment: @JackM If $a^n + b^n$ is an integer, and $|b| < 1$, then when $n$ is large, $b^n$ will be very small.  What happens when you take an integer and add or subtract a very small number to it?  Why is it that $b^n$ approximates $\pm 10^{-n}$?  Because $|5 - \sqrt{26}| \approx 10^{-1}$.  But these are the things that I expect an astute observer to be able to figure out for oneself, rather than asking for more details without taking the time to think about it.

Comment: I misread the numbers in the OP, I thought the numbers began with a mix of 0s and 9s rather than strings of only 0s or only 9s, which seemed harder to explain. Although, we still have an interesting pattern that the decimal expansion always begins $000...09$ or $999...90$, never $000...05$ for instance.

Answer (score 2):

So take $a=5+\sqrt {26}, b=5-\sqrt {26}$ and note that $0\lt -b \lt 1$ (in fact $b \approx -0.1$)

Now note that $a+b=10$ and $ab=-1$ [whence $a=-\frac 1b$ and you can verify the estimate for $b$, because $a\gt 10$]

So $a$ and $b$ are roots of the quadratic $x^2-10x-1=0$ or $x^2=10x+1$ or $x^{n+2}=10x^{n+1}+x^n$

Let $Y_n=a^n+b^n$ then $Y_{n+2}=a^{n+2}+b^{n+2}=10a^{n+1}+a_n+10b^{n+1}+b_n=10Y_{n+1}+Y_n$

Or to summarise, we have the recurrence $Y_{n+2}=10Y_{n+1}+Y_n$

Now note that $Y_0=a^0+b^0=2; Y_1=a+b=10$ and you will find that the $Y_n$ are integers for all $n$ using the recurrence.

But also $Y_n=a^n+b^n$ so that $a^n=Y_n-b^n$ and $b$ is small and negative while $Y_n$ is an integer.

This shows why $a_n$ is nearly an integer and why it is alternately greater than or less than an integer.

The phenomena here come under the title "recurrence relations" or "difference equations" or the sums of powers of roots fo an equation. The simplest and best known is the Fibonacci sequence. This can all look like magic and "where does it come from?" but in fact is really quite elementary.

Comment: This answer should also gain some credit, because it brings some details not included in the answer I have accepted (althought the accepted answer helped me the most)

Answer (score 1):

This phenomenon reminds of the Fibonacci sequence, that follows the recurrence

$$F_{n}=F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}$$ with initial values such that $F_n$ is always an integer.

$$0,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,\cdots$$

At the same time, it can be shown that

$$F_n=\frac{\phi^n-\psi^{-n}}{\sqrt 5}$$ where $\phi$ and $\psi$ are the roots of the characteristic question $x^2=x+1$. As $|\psi|<1$, we have that $|\psi^n|\ll1$, and $\dfrac{\phi^n}{\sqrt 5}$ is close to an integer.

As said by @heropup, your case corresponds to the recurrence

$$M_n=10M_{n-1}+M_{n-2}$$
and the whole sequence is
$$-10,2,10,102,1030,10402,1050500,\cdots$$

Comment: There is a whole class of such numbers, called [Pisot-Vijayaraghavan numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pisot%E2%80%93Vijayaraghavan_number), of which one is the golden ratio.